Automated solution for serving Vite React frontend with Express?
When I build a MERN web site, I typically use Vite React to build the frontend and Express for the backend. In the past, I have used different hosts: for example, GitHub.com for the frontend and Render.com for the backend. This means that I need to use the cors Node module to allow communication with the backend.
Now I have my own dedicated server, and I realize that Vite creates a dist/ folder when you run npm run build. This folder contains a set of static files.
Express can deliver such static files, using express.static(<relative path>). I can place the contents of the dist/ folder in the folder that Express uses for the static files, and so I only need to configure Nginx for a single server. I can use git to push the enriched backend to my dedicated server in a single operation. CORS is not needed, because the frontend and the backend share the same origin.
This would also work with a commercial hosting service like Render.
This requires some manual moving of files. I am guessing that I am not the first person to think of this. Is there an automated technique (such as a Node Module) that already exists for doing this. Or do I have to write my own?

You can server the frontend build using nginx and the backend using pm2.
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name your-domain.com;  # Replace with your domain or IP

  root /path/to/your/frontend/build;  # Path to your frontend build directory
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}

pm2 start backend/server.js --name backend-server

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name your-domain.com;

  # Frontend configuration
  root /path/to/your/frontend/build;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # Backend API configuration
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Replace with your backend server's address
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

OR you can use the s3 static site serving from amazon.

I can, but that is not what I have chosen to do. I already have the Nginx configuration working. My question is about automatically transferring the contents of the Vite dist/ folder to the Express static/ folder, during development as well as for deployment. I have my own dedicated server. I do not want to use a third-party hosting service like Amazon.

Okay, for that yo can use pipeline to automate copying the dist or build folder files to the backend static folder.

Let me know iff you need someone for doing that.

I am not looking for someone who can do it. I am asking if someone has already done it.

Okay, create script in yml and add it to the .github/workflows/filename.yml
write the yaml script in this to establish an SSH connection to your server and then run commands to perform the certain tasks, let me know if you need an example script.
